# How to call Ajax.BeginForm from a custom helper method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Can I call Ajax.BeginFrom from a custom helper method ?

AjaxHelper is not available in a custom helper method, so I tried to pass the "Ajax" available in ViewPage to Helper method while calling it, but then in method, BeginForm is not available on that passed "Ajax" parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could instantiate it:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Foo(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var ajaxHelper = new AjaxHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext, htmlHelper.ViewDataContainer);

        var form = ajaxHelper.BeginForm();
        // ... use the ajaxHelper and htmlHelper
    }
}
```

or if you are writing an extension method on AjaxHelper:

```
public static class AjaxExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Foo(this AjaxHelper AjaxHelper)
    {
        var htmlHelper = new HtmlHelper(AjaxHelper.ViewContext, AjaxHelper.ViewDataContainer);
        // ... use the ajaxHelper and htmlHelper
    }
}
```

And don't forget the proper usings if you want to bring other extension methods into scope:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
```